# What is another way to implement apple sign-in in a django API project without creating an apple developer profile?

Tags: ios, django, apple-sign-in

Apple bills $99 to create a developer profile. Is there a way to override that step in implementing apple sign-in in my django project ?

I tried implementing apple sign in and was expecting to create a free developer profile but unfortunately, I was asked to pay the sum of $99

Comment: I doubt. It is 99 for a reason.

Comment: You must have a paid developer account to use Sign in with Apple.

Comment: You have to set it up in identifiers, which require a developer profile. I highly doubt you can go around this.